# How to prevent outgoing UDP flood

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, ddos, udp

I've been googling for hours now but can't find a sure or helpful answer.
I need to disable high-volume outgoing UDP from my server.

I'm trying to configure APF because of the RAB functionality, but fail because the module ipt_recent is not enabled. No luck with modprobe either.

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:507 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-042stab103.6/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ipt_recent not found.
```

I have installed Deflate, but it was before the attacks happened so it's probably not working.

Can someone point me in the right direction to either fix the ipt_recent module, or a completely different angle to deny the outgoing UDP flood?

Comment: What flavor of UDP flood? If it's DNS, then one solution might be to not offer recursion on the DNS server, or some nameservers now ship with rate throttling mechanisms.

Comment: http. The attacker used port 80 to flood. I've set up APF so UDP port 80 is not accessible anymore.

Comment: If the flood is coming from your server, then it is compromised and should be reinstalled.

Comment: Is it a real VPS, or a mere container (and if the latter, is it by any chance OpenVZ)?